# [h!tp], [H] and [h!t] not working for floats

Tags: floats

In my document I have four graphs that I have tried to fix in place under a given subsection and they keep moving to other parts of my document under different subsections.

I am using `{float}` and have tried [h!tp], [H] and [h!t].... any ideas?

Comment: The description "they keep moving to other parts of my document" is not very specific. Where do they "move" to? To the top of the next page, maybe? Please advise.

Comment: They have spread across the following two pages which happens to be in a different \subsection of my document. They are no longer together and are not contained within the \subsection{results and analysis} section of my document instead have moved to the discussion..... they have parts of my discussion text interspersed in between each graph ...

Comment: If you must prevent `floats` from wandering past the next `\subsection` instruction, you should load the [placeins](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/placeins) package in the preamble and insert the instruction `\FloatBarrier` in all places beyond which the currently pending floats must not move. Doing this will also let you dispense with tedious and not entirely reliable positioning directives such as `[ht!]` and `[H]`.

Comment: I'm going propose to close this posting as the topic of keeping floats "close" to where they're first mentioned has already come up repeatedly.

Comment: The order doesn't matter but why `!` in the middle? I'd always put it first, it affects `h` and `t` equally so `[!ht]` seems more natural than `[h!t]` (and both make it quite likely the float goes to the end of the document as they omit `p`)